# Question about lower convex hull of a polytope

Tags: geometry, polytopes

Question about lower convex hull of a polytope.

Consider the pyramid with triangular $black$ face as the base of the pyramid.

[image]

This is a polytope constructed of $4$ coordinate points ($3$ at the plane and one at the top) in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

**My question:**

What would be the lower convex hull of the pyramid (polytope)?

We know that a convex is divided into two parts, lower convex hull and upper convex hull.

From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull), we get the lower convex hull is formed by those vertices whose upward ray doesn't intersect the convex hull.

So this shows that in case of pyramid shown above, only the $3$ points in the plane contribute the lower convex hull which is just the $black$ face attached with the ground, because upward rays from these $3$ points don't intersect the pyramid.

Am I right about that ?

Comment: Where on the Wikipedia page can I find the "lower convex hull"? Anyway, I think all the other non-black faces are also part of the lower convex hull, aren't they?

Comment: @M.Winter, In the link, go to the paragraph entitled $\text{upper and lower hull}$. I don't think so that other faces are part of lower convex hull according to law.

Comment: This subsection was hidden in the "Definition" section and wasn't obvious to find on mobile. I think you got the definition the wrong way around: what you are defining is the *upper* convex hull. The lower convex hull should consist of exactly the black triangle. And then the other faces must belong to the upper convex hull. Think about it: any ray starting at a point of one of these faces, going upwards, will not intersect the pyramid.

Comment: @M.Winter, thanks.Yes i am also saying that only the black triangle face belong to the lower hull,other faces belong to upper  hull. I wanted to confirm it. Thanks for help